# Firebase functions HttpsError missing details prop and code always set to "cancelled"

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, nuxt.js

I'm throwing an HttpsError from a firebase function

```js
throw new functions.https.HttpsError("not-found", "No user found with this email", "here are some meaningless details");
```

When I catch the error on the client the code is always set to 'cancelled' and the details prop is set to unknown? I'm calling the firebase function from a nuxt app using @nuxtjs/firebase

```js
async submit() {
   try{
      const loginWithEmailFunc = this.$fire.functions.httpsCallable('loginWithEmail')
      const loginWithEmailResponse = await loginWithEmailFunc({
            userEmail: this.email.toLowerCase().trim()
      })

   } catch(error){
      console.error('Code: ' + error.code, 'Message: ' + error.message, 'Details:', error.details)
   }
}
```

Comment: Is the issue resolved?